# Visa for a PhD (and TA) in Canada for Swiss citizens

Tags: visa, canada, study

I am a Swiss student (Citizenship + Nationality + Place of Birth: Switzerland) and I just got accepted by a PhD program at the University of British Columbia (UBC), Canada. There is tons of information online but I don't manage to make sure which kind of Visa I should apply for.

Should I apply on [this page](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/my_application/apply_online.asp) for a study permit or for a permanent resident status?

Notes: I will be working as a Teaching Assistant (TA) at UBC. I have never studied in Canada (only in the USA as an exchange student during my Bachelor).

Comment: UBC has an [International Student Development office](http://students.ubc.ca/international).  They should be able to tell you exactly what you need.  In fact, there's a good  chance they'll contact you directly if you don't contact them first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually as @NateEldredge pointed out most of the information you're able to find from the [University of British Columbia International Student Guide](http://students.ubc.ca/international) as a student or a PhD student you are able to work [on Campus](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/work-oncampus.asp) as part of your study permit.  In addition depending on your citizenship you may require a [TRV](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/visas.asp?country=Switzerland) to enter Canada but since you hold Swiss passport this is not required for you.

In addition to all of the above there were rule changes that went into effect on June 1, 2014 that also provides for ability to work [off campus](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/study-changes.asp) provided you meet [eligibility criteria](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/work-offcampus.asp) as listed on the page or you will have to apply for a separate [Work permit](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/study/work.asp).