# How long does a Work Permit last in Canada?

Tags: visa, working-visas, canada

My girlfriend is from Sweden. She is coming to Canada with me and has a Work Permit already.

Question 1:  How long can she stay in Canada on a Work Permit?

Question 2:  Does she need any other type of visa to enter (Temporary Resident Visa or Visitors Visa) or is a Work Permit enough?

Comment: Related: http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/1381/visa-for-a-phd-and-ta-in-canada-for-swiss-citizens

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but that link doesn't answer my question at all… 

That's more in terms of working on campus being a student. And the part that does mention a work permit doesn't answer my question.

Comment: It answers the 2nd Question.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, but it doesn't at all.

Comment: *In addition depending on your citizenship you may require a TRV to enter Canada but since you hold Swiss passport this is not required for you.* - It doesn't?

Comment: Swiss != Sweden...

Comment: Swiss is not the same as Swedish.. So no.
-   Swiss = Switzerland    -     Sweden = Swedish

Comment: @MarkMayo Ok.  So let's follow the link for TRV change Switzerland to Sweden and obtain the same result.  And no Swiss isn't Sweden but possible necessity of TRV based on citizenship doesn't change.

Comment: @Jake Yes I know but the page linked in that answer for TRV necessity doesn't change...

Comment: I was just going to comment about how Sweden is also  not required to need a TRV. I was just pointing out that what you said specifically didn't answer my question and educating you on the difference between Swedish and Swiss.

Comment: But I will admit, the TRV link did, in fact, answer the second Question. So thank you for that. Now I just need to find out how long it's for. (BTW sorry for sounding like a D!^# in the last comment..)

Comment: Can anyone give me their opinion on this..? There is not expiration date written on the Work Permit form, but there is this……-------------------------------------------------IMPORTANT: Regulations have established a maximum cumulative duration of four years that a Temporary
Foreign Worker can work in Canada. After four years of work has been accumulated, a period of 48 months
spent not working in Canada must elapse before another work permit can be issued, with some limited
exceptions.------------------------------------Does that mean she has a 4 year working visa…? It doesn't sound right...

Comment: @Jake I don't actually know but the word “cumulative” suggests that it's not the case but that even with several consecutive visa she wouldn't be allowed to stay more than four years under this status in any case.

Comment: A work permit as “temporary foreign worker” is apparently linked with a specific job (you need to apply for an extension if you want to switch employers). I couldn't find any definitive information on this either but it make the duration of the visa less relevant.

Comment: I guess the question I *should* have asked is "Is a Work Permit" the same as a "Working Holiday Visa" for Canada.

Comment: @Jake No, working holiday is a much more limited program (e.g. it's only open to young people from certain countries).

Comment: Incidentally, I don't think the TRV link answers the question at all, it's about visits and transit.

Comment: If it helps answering at all, the following link is the process in which we followed in obtaining the "Work Permit" and why we thought it was a Work Visa

-------------------------
http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/sweden-suede/experience_canada_experience/application_guide-guide_demande.aspx---------------------   If you click "Working Holiday" on the left hand side selection bar, then go to the bottom and click "Start application" it brings to back to the link I sent here.

Comment: @Gala If you read the whole answer and the links in it it states that for a study permit you may need a TRV in addition to the permit.  This doesn't answer Q1 or anything about the Working Holiday visa.

Comment: @Karlson I read the answer *and* the link but it's completely unclear whether it applies here at all.

Comment: @Gala http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/work/apply-who.asp 2nd Heading 4th bullet point last sentence.

Answer (score 4):

I want to let you know that I am not an immigration attorney, just someone very interested in Canadian immigration.

1. Honestly, I don't think there is an issue with the duration of the work permit. If she has a regular work permit that was acquired through a labour market opinion, it can be renewed as long as you are working for the company that sponsoured the work permit. However, if her job is a HRSDC 0 (management), A (university education required) or B (college education required) position, she can apply for permanent residency under the Canadian Experience Class.
2. According to CIC, she doesn't need a temporary resident visa because of her nationality. This is assuming, of course, that she is not found inadmissible due to medical or criminal reasons... but I seriously doubt that this would be an issue now that she has a work permit in hand.

Comment: The work permit was obtained through the Working Holiday section of the site below (on the left). She doesn't have a sponsor or a job yet. I thought it was a working visa.

http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/sweden-suede/experience_canada_experience/application_guide-guide_demande.aspx

So i don't know if that's the same thing you did..

Answer (score 2):

I came to Canada on a work permit.
Mine was tied to my job and my company.
It was valid for 2 years. It was extended twice until I eventually was granted the status of a Permanent Resident.

The work permit of your girlfriend should state for how long it is valid.
It should also state what type of work she is permitted to do under the permit.
You might not be able to attend a university, college or other educational institutions under that work permit.

Please check carefully.

EDIT:
I knew this as "Work & Travel Visa" from other occasions. It's definitively different from what I did. But my daughter did it when she came to do a stint for a month.

http://www.canadainternational.gc.ca/sweden-suede/experience_canada_experience/working_holiday-vacances_travail.aspx

> The Working Holiday category is designed for Swedish citizens who intend to travel in Canada and who wish to find temporary paid employment to help pay for their stay (maximum 12 months).

So if I read the web page correctly then your girlfriends visa will be valid for 12 months.

Comment: The work permit was obtained through the Working Holiday section of the site below (on the left). She doesn't have a sponsor or a job yet. I thought it was a working visa. canadainternational.gc.ca/sweden-suede/… So i don't know if that's the same thing you did.